# NSUserDefaults Loosing Value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Update: I've tried changing setValue to setObject, and the same error occurred.Upon further investigation with breakpoints and the LLDB, they are nil before the controller is even presented. I'm not saving them right.

I'm trying to simply save a couple of strings of text, and display them on another view using Swift. I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time. Here is how I'm trying to accomplish this:
VC1

```
@IBAction func registerTapped(sender : AnyObject) 
        // Save the login information

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        defaults.setValue(username.text, forKey: "username")
        defaults.setValue(password.text, forKey: "password")


        if firstName.text.isEmpty == false {
            defaults.setValue(firstName.text, forKey: "firstname")
        }

        if lastName.text.isEmpty == false {
            defaults.setValue(lastName.text, forKey: "lastname")
        }

        let profileView = ProfileViewController()
        self.presentViewController(profileView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Cool. That looks like the correct way to save strings in UITextFields based upon my research. So, I open up VC2 and try to load the saved text into the new UITextField's, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        username.text = defaults.stringForKey("username")
        password.text = defaults.stringForKey("password")

        if let first = defaults.stringForKey("firstname")
        {
            firstName.text = first
        }
        if let last = defaults.stringForKey("lastname") {
            lastName.text = last
        }
}
```

I get the crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I've been digging through tutorials for hours and can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Is it because it an an optional? This is my LLDB output:
[image]

Comment: Use `setObject: forKey:` instead of `setValue: forKey:`

Comment: Tried that already, did not work.

Comment: `defaults.synchronize()`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I've tried adding that in as well, right after saving the data. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do `NSUserDefaults`, whats `nil` are your labels `username`, `password`, etc. in your second controller.

You should add a segue to your button (the one with `registerTapped`) to show the second controller and remove the last two lines in `registerTapped`.

Answer (score 0):

Break your code into steps and debug each one. Your code would crash if your outlet is nil or if the key/value pair doesn't exist. Check that both username and password (The text fields) are not nil, as well as that the defaults results aren't nil:

```
var text: String?

text = defaults.stringForKey("username")
if let text = text
{
  if let username = username
  {
  username.text = text
  }
  else
  {
    println("username field is nil!")
  }
}
else
{
  println("defaults stringForKey("username") = nil!")
}

text = defaults.stringForKey("password")
if let text = text
{
  if let password = password
  {
  password.text = text
  }
  else
  {
    println("password field is nil!")
  }
}
else
{
  println("defaults stringForKey("password") = nil!")
}
```